# Angular 2: define static variable based on environment

Tags: angular

is it possible to define a static variable based on environment?

Something like (this code is a silly example but it holds the idea):

```
if (environment.production) {
   public static MY_VAR: string = 'A';
} else {
   public static MY_VAR: string = 'B';
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `public static MY_VAR = environment.production ?  'A' : 'B'` ?

Comment: Thanks that is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

what i do is read the url from window.location.host when the application is bootstrapped for the first time and then according to the dev,qa and uat url i set the api endpoint in my application.
How to achieve this?

in your main.ts file

```
 platformBrowserDynamic([{provide:'EndPoint',useValue:config.getEndPoint()}])

export class config{
public static getEndPoint(){
const host = window.location.host
if(host) // your logic goes here{

}
}
}
```

In your service inject it like

```
constructor(@Inject('EndPoint') private endPoint:string)
```